# getting the length of an array using strlen in g++ compiler

Tags: c++, string, cstring, strlen

could someone explain why i am getting this error when i am compiling the source using following g++ compiler

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char source_language[50];


    scanf("%16s\n",source_language);

    int length = sizeof(source_language);
    int sizeofchar = strlen(source_language);
    printf("%d\n",sizeofchar);
}
```

this gives me following error

test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:

test.cpp:31: error: ‘strlen’ was not declared in this scope

when i change the `#include <string>` into  `#include <string.h>`  or `#include<cstring>` , it works fine, i need to figure out what is the difference using `#include<string>` and `#include<string.h>` . really appreciate any help

Comment: Can you edit the question for clarity?  "when I change #include into #incude or #include" is missing some information, I think.

Comment: ok, done, thanx for showing it up

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++ programmers normally have to deal with at least 2 flavours of string: raw C-style strings, usually declared as `char *str;` or `char str[123];`, which can be manipulated with `strlen()` etc.; and C++-style strings, which have the type `std::string` and are manipulated with member functions like `string::length()`.  Unfortunately this leads to a bit of confusion.

- In C, `#include <string.h>` declares `strlen()` et al.
- In C++, you need `#include <cstring>` instead, which declares them in the `std` namespace, so you can either call these functions as `std::strlen()` etc. or you need to follow up with `using namespace std;`, in which case you can then just call them as `strlen()` etc. as usual.
- C++ *also* has a totally separate header called `<string>`, which declares the C++ type `std::string`.  This header has nothing to do with `strlen()`, so including it will not let you access `strlen()`.

I don't know why Mehrdad Afshari deleted his answer, which I'm essentially repeating here.

Answer (score 13):

You are trying to use `strlen` function, which is declared in `string.h` (or, as a member of namespace `std` in `cstring`). So, in order to use `strlen` you should include one of those two headers.

The `#include <string>` variant does not work simply because `string` is a completely unrelated C++-specific header file which has absolutely *nothing* to do with C standard library string functions. What made you expect that it will work?

Answer (score 4):

```
#include<string>
```

this include is for c++ std::string, not c string (link: http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/string/start)

and those:

```
#include<cstring>
```

and

```
#include<string.h>
```

are for c strings (link: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/)

Answer (score 0):

use string.length() instead of strlen()